# How to exclude localhost requests from security-constraint in Weblogic

Tags: security, authentication, authorization, weblogic

Weblogic container security is enabled by protecting URLs using security-constraint tag:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>MyApp</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>
        Admin
       </role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
```

And URLs which do not need to be protected are excluded using another security-constraint tag without auth-constraint tag as follows:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Excluded</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/servlet/internalPollServlet</url-pattern>
      <url-pattern>/servlet/internalScheduler</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
  </security-constraint>
```

The URLs that are excluded are server to server calls (One web app to another within Weblogic) which need not be protected. The problem we face is that there are a lot of different web apps that communicate this way and we don't have a documented list of such server to server calls.

So is there a way we can exclude all URLs/requests which are from localhost/127.0.0.1 from protection ?